# Linq to Enity complex query

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have entity which contains `Id, Price` columns

I want to build `linq to entiy` query which would `count` the number of rows, summarize the `Price` and than subtract `count` from `Price` and multiplied the result by `one hounded`.

```
(Count(*) - SUM(Price))*100
```

Is it possible to create such single query with entity framework 4.0?

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
var ris = (from p in dc.Products  group p by p into a  select   (a.Count() - a.Sum(z => z.UnitPrice)) * 100).First();
```

or

```
 var ris= dc.ExecuteStoreQuery<double>("select (Count(*) - SUM(Price))*100 from mytable");
```